# sed: -e expression #1, char 43: unknown option to `s'

Tags: sed

I am trying to replace a variable value in my file using bash.

```
Input string ----- preprocess_date=06/24/2020_17:00

Expected string ----- preprocess_date=06/24/2020_17:10
```

I have the value `06/24/2020_17:10` in `prep_tmp` variable. I have tried the below command:

```
sed -i s/preprocess_date=.*/preprocess_date=${prep_tmp}/
```

I'm getting the error `` sed: -e expression #1, char 43: unknown option to `s' ``

Can anyone help me on this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: use "-s around your sed expression and a diff separator: ```sed -i "s#preprocess_date=.*#preprocess_date=${prep_tmp}#"```

Comment: Please note when you search here for `[sed] unknown option to` there are already 270 Q/As.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your command with the 3 seperating `/`:

```
sed -i s/preprocess_date=.*/preprocess_date=${prep_tmp}/
        ^                  ^                           ^
```

expands to:

```
sed -i s/preprocess_date=.*/preprocess_date=06/24/2020_17:10/
        ^                  ^                  ^
```

with `24/2020_17:10/` overflowing after the `s` command

To solve this problem you can replace all the sperarating `/` with some other character. I like using the `|` (but also needs `"` to ensure that they are not parsed as pipes by a shell)

```
sed -i "s|preprocess_date=.*|preprocess_date=${prep_tmp}|"
```